# Toggle info for each product

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am using OpenCart v2.2.0. On category page I have Show/Hide link for each product belonging to the category, which is supposed to shor or hide product info. The problem is it toggles only for first product info, no matter which Show/Hide link I click. Others don't toggle their info, they all toggle the first only. So far I have this code:

In category.tpl:

```
<div class="caption">

    <h4><a style="width:140%;" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
    <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent');" style="padding: 5px 10px;">Show/Hide</a>
    <div id="myContent" style="display:none;">
        <p class="description"><b>About:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
            <?php if ($product['manufacturer']) { ?>
            <b><?php echo "<strong>Manufacturer:</strong>" ?></b> <a href="<?php echo $product['manufacturers']?>"><span itemprop="brand"><?php echo $product['manufacturer']; ?></span></a>
            <?php } ?></br>
    <?php echo "<strong>For models:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $product['model']; ?></br>
            <?php echo "<strong>Manufacturer code:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $product['mpn']; ?></br>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Also there is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
</script>
```

Does anyone know how do I make others toggle their own info as well? I've been trying to solve this with no luck, obviously. This is all I came up with, but it is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers were helpful, but my solution was to pass product_id and that way every div would toggle separately when I click Show/Hide link. So, the code is as my original, except for these two lines where I actually pass product_id:

```
  <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('myContent<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" style="padding: 5px 10px;">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="myContent<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Identifiers in HTML must be uniuqe.** You can use common class to target the element. I would recommend you to use unobstrsive event handler and bind event using jQuery  [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method.

You can use various method to traverse DOM.

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggleDiv').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this) //Current element
           .closest('.caption') //Travese up to get common parent
           .find('.myContent') //Get Element using class
           .toggle();
    })
});
```

*HTML*, Here added `toggleDiv` to anchor element and `myContent` to content div

```
<div class="caption">
    <h4><a style="width:140%;" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class='toggleDiv' style="padding: 5px 10px;">Show/Hide</a>
    <div class="myContent" style="display:none;">
        <p class="description"><b>About:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
        <?php if ($product['manufacturer']) { ?>
        <b><?php echo "<strong>Manufacturer:</strong>" ?></b> <a href="<?php echo $product['manufacturers']?>"><span itemprop="brand"><?php echo $product['manufacturer']; ?></span></a>
        <?php } ?></br>
         <?php echo "<strong>For models:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $product['model']; ?></br>
        <?php echo "<strong>Manufacturer code:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $product['mpn']; ?></br>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for the reply. When I implement your code, nothing happens. Show/Hide link doesn't toggle even the first one. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The working snippet shows for the first only. I'm going crazy :)

Comment: @Nancy, Sorry did not updated second div https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0jjyvn4j/1/

Comment: Weird thing is, this example doesn't work on my page. When I click on the Show/Hide link, it gets me to the front page of my website.

Answer (score 1):

First the `id` should be unique in the same document so replace the duplicate ones by general classes then use those classes for the selection, example give your anchors `a` a class like `toggle` in my example then attach the click event to the class :

```
$('body').on('click','.toggle',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('.caption').find('.myContent').toggle();
  //Or
  $(this).next('.myContent').toggle();
})
```

I suggest here to avoid the use of the inline-event `onclick` and to attach the click event from your javascript code.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('click','.toggle',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    
  $(this).closest('.caption').find('.myContent').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="caption">
  <h4>    <a style="width:140%;" href="">Name1</a></h4>
  <a href="" style="padding: 5px 10px;" class='toggle'>Show/Hide</a>
  <div class="myContent" style="display:none;">
    <p class="description"><b>About:</b>&nbsp;description1</p>
    <b><strong>Manufacturer:</strong></b> 
    <a href="">
      <span itemprop="brand">manufacturer</span>
    </a>
    <br>
    <strong>For models:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Manufacturer code:&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>

<div class="caption">
  <h4><a style="width:140%;" href="">Name2</a></h4>
  <a href="" style="padding: 5px 10px;" class='toggle'>Show/Hide</a>
  <div class="myContent" style="display:none;">
    <p class="description"><b>About:</b>&nbsp;description2</p>
    <b><strong>Manufacturer:</strong></b> 
    <a href="">
      <span itemprop="brand">manufacturer</span>
    </a>
    <br>
    <strong>For models:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;Manufacturer code:&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```